# java call a method, very beginning mode

Tags: java, methods

I know maybe this question is very simple, but in my first steps with Java it's a wall that don't let me continue. I have the next code:

```
package com.bpe.primitive;

class TestPrimitives {
    int a = 4;
    int b = 5;
    int c;

    public int bar(int num1, int num2, int num3)
    {
        num3=num1+num2;
        System.out.println(num3);
    }

    com.bpe.primitive.bar();
    //int res = new TestPrimitives.bar(a, b);
}
```

Like you can see, I try to call the method "bar", but I can't, I try in the classical way of other programs like PHP: 'bar(a, b)', but nothing. And... I don't know why or hoy can I call 'bar' with the two parameters.

Comment: Event if `com.bpe.primitive.bar();` were a valid symbol (it's not), it can't be outside a method. You'd need an instance of `TestPrimitives`.

Comment: You're trying to call the method from *outside* the method, just in the class declaration. You're also trying to call a method that has three parameters without specifying any arguments. It's unclear why you've *got* three parameters when you overwrite the value of the third parameter immediately...

Comment: Change that third parameter to a local variable, and return it.

Comment: `new TestPrimitives()./*create a new instance*/bar(a, b, c);/*call its method*/` and put this line in a method (e.g. `public static void main(String... a)`)

Comment: Couple of things, 1. Add a main method and call `bar` from there 2. your bar method only requires two parameters and third one should be returned.

Comment: I suggest you work through the Java tutorials provided by Oracle.  They cover the basics very well.

Comment: You may find the basic java tutorial here at http://www.javatpoint.com/java-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "do stuff", e.g. call a method, you first off all need a method. The entry point for Java programs is the `main` method. Also your method `bar` is non-static, i.e. it belongs to an object. You thus need to instantiate an object first:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  TestPrimitives tp = new TestPrimitives();
  tp.bar(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Or you can declare `bar` as `public static int...` and then call it directly:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  bar(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation, it's help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TestPrimitives {
int a = 4;
int b = 5;
int c;

public static int bar(int num1, int num2, int num3)
{
    num3=num1+num2;
    System.out.println(num3);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
TestPrimitives.bar(1,2,3);
}
```

This method is static, so it belongs to the class. Think of it as a class method, not as an object method. If you don't declare it static, you need to instantiate an object from that class:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
TestPrimitives test = new TestPrimitives();
test.bar(1,2,3);
}
```

You need to call the methods from the main method.

Answer (score 0):

- First thing in Java, you need to define the main() method & you may call the same within main() method.
- Second If you want to call bar with two parameters & return the result your code will be something like this.

  ```
  package com.bpe.primitive;
  class TestPrimitives {

  public int bar(int num1, int num2)
  {
      return num1 + num2;
  }

  public static void main(String [] args){
  int a = 4;
  int b = 5;
  int c;
     TestPrimitives test = new TestPrimitives();
     c = test.bar(a,b);
     System.out.println(c);
  }}
  ```